# What is the entropy of a random variable $X$ which denotes the number of rolls of a fair die required to get an outcome less than or equal to $3$

Tags: probability, information-theory, entropy

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Me62.png)

I know that $H(x) = -\sum(p(x_i)\log(p(x_i))$

And I have found $P(x_i)=1/6\cdot(5/6)^{i-1}$

However I do not know how to calculate this when I put $P(x_i)$ into the formula $H(x)$

Comment: Where did you arrive at the equation $P(x_i) = \frac{1}{6} (\frac{5}{6})^{i-1}$?

Comment: Oops it should have been 3/6 and 3/6 actually. I was thinking of it landing on one number (P(x1) = 1/6 i.e gets on first roll, P(x2) = 1/6*5/6 gets on second etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is $\le 3$, $P(x_i)=(\frac{1}{2})^i$.  Therefore $H(x)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{2})^i \, i \ln{2}=2 \ln{2}$.

Note I used $\ln((\frac{1}{2})^i)=i \ln(1/2)$ with $\ln(1/2)=-\ln 2$ and $\sum_{i=1}^\infty i\,(\frac{1}{2})^i=2$.

Comment: The entropy is negative?  (Generally, $H(x) = -\sum p_i \log p_i$, isn't it?)

Comment: Error on my part.  I forgot  "-" in the original definition.  It's been corrected.

Comment: How did you get the $sum(i*(1/2)^i) = 2$ ?

Comment: General formula for$(|x|\lt 1),S(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty kx^k=x\sum_{k=1}^\infty kx^{k-1}=x\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{d}{dx}x^k=x\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^k=x\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x}{1-x}=x\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$  For $x=\frac{1}{2}$ the expression $S(\frac{1}{2})=2$.

Comment: To avoid calculus, lay out $S(x)$ in a two dimensional array with rows corresponding to $k$ and columns corresponding to $x^k$.  Each row then sums to $\frac{x^k}{1-x}$ and the sum of the rows is $\frac {x}{(1-x)^2}$.